# can not access storage files (all files) on android 10.0 or less on android 10+ working fine

Tags: flutter, dart

I added the followning permissions in manifist file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE_INTERNAL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
added this in application attribute
```

I am using permissions handler package to request for permissions, My app working fine on 10+ android phones but not working on 10.0 or less. Access denied exception showing when I try to get files from storage.

I am using [Photo Gallery Package](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_gallery) for getting photos, this is not working on android 10.0 or less. how to solve permission issue on android 10.0 or less?